# hidden data update in php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, procedure

I'd like to make (because I cannot say I already have it..) a script that I will have to add 2 values "pesel" (something like id), and "id_ubezpieczenia" (just another id of thing), but update 3 "pesel", "id_ubezpieczenia" AND "date".

Here is example code I have:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
$nazwabazydanych = "projekt";

$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);
$is_ubezpieczenia = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['is_ubezpieczenia']);  
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);


if (!$pesel || !$id_ubezpieczenia || !$data)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }

if ('pesel' != 11)

{
      print "Zły numer pesel.";
      exit;
}


$db = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db)  
        {  
        print "Nie można nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych";
        exit;
        }

mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");

$query = mysql_query("CALL skladka ('$pesel','$id_ubezpieczenia','$data')"); 
print "Porwierdzono dodanie do skladek.";

?>
```

It requires me to make procedure skladka with 3 values, but I want to make it only 2 values with hidden autp updating value of date. When I say auto updating I mean I want the field date to be current date.

Any help with this one?

In conclusion:

I want to have on my page a site where there are 2 fields to add: 
"pesel" and "id_ubezpeiczenia". While in my database it will update 3 fields ("date" as well with current date).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your MySQL table add 
a column of type

```
TIMESTAMP
```

And set its options to

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

e.g. :

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```